# Can I use a global constant in Angular without injection into controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

In coffeescript, I defined a constant object:

```
angular
.module 'main',
    []

.constant 'CONFIG',
    IMAGEROOT: 'http://some-img.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/'
```

In html, I use the constant like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{CONFIG.IMAGEROOT}}assets/img/
```

This can be done like this:

```
.controller 'HomeCtrl', ($scope, CONFIG) ->
    $scope.CONFIG=CONFIG
```

While this works well, every controller needs to start with `$scope.CONFIG=CONFIG`, which looks quite clumsy.. Is there a way to make a constant global (accessible for any $scope)?

Is the right way to add a outmost controller (parent scope) to store this constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add CONFIG to a "parent" scope (an outer elements's scope) or to [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope).

Note, directives with isolated scopes will not inherit properties from "parent" divs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do only one thing in your app.run() block apply values to $rootScope that can be accessed across the application.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  // you can inject any instance here
 $rootScope.IMAGEROOT='http://some-img.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/';
});
```

Ps:-But the prefer way is to use constant and inject them in controller as you already said in your question. 
And you can only use it in run block because config block will not provide you to use service of $rootScope.